# Convert String inside h:outputText into capitalize String?

Tags: java, jsf, seam

How can I convert a String in h:outputText? Here is the code of h:outputText:

```
<h:outputText value="#{item.label} : " />
```

I tried using this,

```
<s:convertStringUtils format="capitalize" trim="true"/>
```

But it gives me error :
"no tag was defined for name: convertStringUtils"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are several ways.

1. Use CSS `text-transform: capitalize` property.

   ```html
   <h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" styleClass="capitalized" />
   ```

   with

   ```css
   .capitalized {
       text-transform: capitalize;
   }
   ```
2. Create a custom [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html).

   ```html
   <h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" converter="capitalizeConverter" />
   ```

   with

   ```
   @Override
   public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
       if (modelValue == null || ((String) modelValue).isEmpty()) {
           return null;
       }

       String string = (String) modelValue;
       return new StringBuilder()
           .append(Character.toTitleCase(string.charAt(0)))
           .append(string.substring(1))
           .toString();
   }
   ```
3. Use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org)' [`of:capitalize()` function](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Strings).

   ```html
   <html ... xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/ui">
   ...
   <h:outputText value="#{of:capitalize(bean.text)}" />
   ```

The `<s:convertStringUtils>` which you're trying is not from Seam. It's from MyFaces Sandbox.

Comment: I do not want to convert to uppercase, i want to make capitalized. But this (number 5) can be applied to make it capitalized as well. Thanks for you efforts.

Comment: Oh right, fixed answer :) CSS one is the easiest IMO. It's purely presentational, right?

Comment: Upon implementation of css option, I noticed that if the string contained '/' or '-'. Then the text would not transform to uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

The following works with JSF 1.2 and Seam 2.x.  It might work without Seam, but I can't recall exactly how Seam extends EL in Java EE 5.

```
<h:outputText value="#{item.label.toUpperCase()} : " />

<!-- If your string could be null -->
<h:outputText value="#{(item.label != null ? item.label.toUpperCase() : '')} : " />
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect in 2 ways: 1) capitalizing is definitely not the same as uppercasing, capitalizing is uppercasing only the 1st character. 2) EL is null-safe, so that nullcheck makes no sense, you just directly use `#{item.label.toUpperCase()}`.

Comment: Good point about unnecessary null checking for property chains in EL; I wasn't aware of this.  I see that this evaluation behavior is specified in the [EL 2.2 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsp-2.1-fr-eval-spec-oth-JSpec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec-el.pdf?AuthParam=1355113088_64a7284fa52e13380c220bc6d64324f4).

Answer (score 0):

create a getter method in your data bean

```
public String getCapitalizeName(){
  return StringUtils.capitalize(getName());
}
```

and on xhtml

```
<houtputText value="#{yourDataBean.capitalizeName}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @BalusC said you can use `text-transform: capitalize;`. But it converts the first letter of each word in your sentence to uppercase. If your requirement is that, that is the best answer because 

 **1.** It is easier
**2.** `text-transform: capitalize;` is supported by all major browsers.

However if you want to capitalize only the very first letter of the sentence you can do something like this.

```
public String getLabel() {
  if(label != null && !label.isEmpty()) {
    return Character.toUpperCase(label.charAt(0)) + label.substring(1);
  }
  return label;
}
```

I don't think that **JBoss Seam** has a `<s:convertStringUtils>` tag. As I think such a tag is available in **Apache MyFaces**. Don't know much about that.